# Flutter custom Icon Font not showing from package

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, icon-fonts

I'm having trouble showing my custom icon font on screen. Android emulator as well as iOS emulator.
I'm importing the icons via a package that generates the font. I previously had them directly in the app repository coming from `assets/fonts`.
What has changed is that they now come from a package and that they are `otf` instead of `ttf`. But as far as I read, the current Flutter version should be able to display `otf`.

Below you can find a screenshot for iOS (left side) and Android (right side).
[image]

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=3.0.0 <4.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  my_font_package:
    git:
      url: git@github.com:MyOrg/my-font.git
      ref: 0.0.3

flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: My Font
      fonts:
        - asset: packages/my_font_package/fonts/my_font.otf
```

When I change the path to the `otf` in any way different, the build compiler will give me an expected error. So the path is finding the file.

```dart
import 'package:my_font_package/my_font.dart';

class MyIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Icon(
      MyFont.eyesolid,
      color: Colors.primary,
      size: 24.0,
    );
  }
}
```

In the font package:

```dart
class MyFont{
  const MyFont._();

  static const iconFontFamily = 'My Font';
  static const iconFontPackage = 'my_font';

  /// Font icon named "__eye-closed__"
  ///
  /// <image width='32px' src='data:image/svg+xml;base64,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'>
  static const IconData eyeclosed = IconData(0xe015,
      fontFamily: iconFontFamily, fontPackage: iconFontPackage);
}
```

I have `flutter clean`, cleaned the cache, turned off the simulator and rebuilt the app multiple times. I'm therefore adding a new question here to see if there are other aspects I have missed.

Interesting aspect:
Android Studio also doesn't give me a preview.
[image]

Perhaps this gives the right direction, or it is a distraction. Who knows?
The previous to the material design icons are working great.

Comment: Does it work in the `example` project of your package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is tricky but visible here.

The font is not a package itself. The class gets to be delivered to the implementation. This is why defining the property `fontPackpage` in the IconData is wrong.

This is wrong since the class and the font are in the same package.

```dart
static const IconData myIcon = IconData(0xe015,
      fontFamily: iconFontFamily, fontPackage: iconFontPackage);
```

It should be:

```dart
static const IconData myIcon = IconData(0xe015,
      fontFamily: iconFontFamily);
```

The result

[image]